# Windows Phone 8 - private APIs?

Tags: api, windows-phone-8, private

Is it possible to use private APIs in Windows Phone 8 development similar to iOS development?

Of course, this is NOT about apps going to get published (AppStore/Marketplace). But there are a lot of use cases for non-public projects where a developer wants to call internal system functions.

With the Windows Phone 8 SDK installed, one can mount the Windows Phone 8 Emulator image located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images`. In the main partition of the Windows Phone OS, one can navigate to Windows\System32 and inspect the system DLL files with a tool like Dependency Walker or IDA Pro.

There are a lot of functions that sound very interesting but which are not publicly available and thus not documented. The question is: is it possible to call them somehow from an app or by other means?

Just a few examples of interesting functions (there are much more):

- ShellChrome.dll: InvokeStartMenu, InvokeScreenCapture, InvokeVolumeUp, LockDevice, ...
- InputInjection.dll: ApiInjectInitialize, ApiInjectTouchEvent, ...
- ...

I tried to get LoadLibrary (specifically, LoadLibraryExA) working somehow in a native Windows Phone App project, and to load and call these functions (the loading of the library worked). Long story short, I ended up with access violation errors or similar when trying to call the functions (maybe because of the sandboxed execution environment). Another problem is, that I can only guess the signatures (arguments) of the functions. I can't find them out with the tools I use.

Answer (score 1):

Private api? We can use dll files in the windows phone. I have used private sdk's in the windows phone. I don't think windows is going to permit us to customize the OS just like Android do, So Invoke volume up..etc stuff is not going to work through private api.

Answer (score 0):

I think they only provide some private apis to only partners with an NDA.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/4af0e87a-ab4b-4652-891a-f198a32758cf/windows-phone-8-access-to-private-apis

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the application sandbox will enforce API usage. That means you will get an UnauthorizedAccessException every time you try to do a call to an api requiring rights you don't have.
This is intimately tied with the developer account you use to unlock your phone for development purposes.

EDIT : That's also true on the c++ native side.